# Perl Template::Toolkit regex matching either values

Tags: regex, perl, template-toolkit

I am trying to match either of the string in the Perl [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aToolkit) module.

`url` is getting its value from the script.

```
[% IF url == ("a/b/c" | "d/e/f") %]
```

Is this the right way of doing it? I looked at the documents. It mentioned the 'matches' method, but I am looking for a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: does the string has double quotes and forward slashes?

Comment: if yes then your regex would be `(\"a\/b\/c\"|\"d\/e\/f\")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj No Success and it is not matching the " . it has forward slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a little awkward to use regular expressions in `Template::Toolkit`, but in this case you can just write

```
[% IF url == 'a/b/c' or url == 'd/e/f' %]
```

If you need anything more complex then you're probably misunderstanding the rôle of templates, but you can always evaluate a Boolean condition within Perl and pass that value into the template

---

**Update**

Or you could use `SWITCH`, like this

```
[% SWITCH url %]
[%   CASE [ 'a/b/c', 'd/e/f' ] %]
       ...
[% END %]
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, though lengthy but helpful, Thanks Borodin ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [match virtual method](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#method_match) to test a regexp. This is as simple as it gets.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;

my $t = Template->new;
$t->process( \*DATA, { urls => [qw(
    http://example.com/a/b/c
    http://example.com/xyz
    http://example.com/x/d/e/f
)] } );

__DATA__
[% FOREACH url IN urls %]
  [%- IF url.match('a/b/c|d/e/f') %]
    [%- url %] - match
  [%- ELSE %]
    [%- url %] - NO match
  [%- END %]
[% END %]
```

Outputs:

```
http://example.com/a/b/c - match
http://example.com/xyz - NO match
http://example.com/x/d/e/f - match
```

Alternatively, perform the match on the URL in your script then pass the boolean outcome to the template.